# Spectral clustering algorithm doesn't use all available clusters

Tags: weighted-graphs, clustering

We have implemented a spectral clustering algorithm according to the article *Multiclass Spectral Clustering* (Yu and Shi, *Proc. IEEE ICCV '03*, vol. 2, pp. 313–319, 2003; [PDF](https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~stellayu/publication/doc/2003kwayICCV.pdf)).

We used the algorithm to test simple cases of clustering and it seems to work, however in some cases the algorithm doesn't use all the available clusters meaning we get some empty clusters.

A few questions:
1) Can spectral clustering give empty clusters? 
* If it can, is there an algorithm that demands that all clusters are occupied?
2) Is there a newer or better algorithm we should consider?

**Below link has a matlab code we wrote and an example:**
* The example is for 20 clusters and a specific weight function.

https://technionmail-my.sharepoint.com/personal/sgiladfe_campus_technion_ac_il/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?folderid=12ab9758bb2af4935aa5f0cda34ecd81b&authkey=AVooH-7f_D1umLEeI5PsREM

Thank you,
Gilad

Comment: Welcome to the site! The link to your code probably isn't needed, since your question is about the algorithm itself, rather than your implementation of it. If the question is really "Is our code buggy?" then that's off-topic, here. You might like to take our brief [tour] for more information on how the site works.

Comment: If you don't like empty clusters, you can simply discard any cluster that is empty.  "Is there a better algorithm that we should consider?" is subjective and probably not answerable without knowing what you mean by better and without knowing what you are using the algorithm for and what your data is like.  Is there a newer clustering algorithm?  Certainly.  People publish clustering algorithms every year.  Whether they're better, though, is a different question...